# How to restart dependent services while restaring service in chef

Tags: chef-infra, recipe

I tried to restart sqlserver using chef. But it failed as sqlserveragent(dependent service) is running on machine. Is there an attribute in service resource to handle this automatically.

```
service "MSSQLSERVER" do
     action     :restart
end
```

Is there best way to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if one service depends on another, you have to kill it first. You can either just kill it with another service resource **before this one** - or set `action :nothing` on *MSSQLSEVER* and then add `notifies` in another one.

Another way, but *not tested* by me, is to set your own `restart_command`, where you first kill that process and then restart your service.

You can find more info [here](https://docs.chef.io/resource_service.html). Unfortunately, there is no parameter to force stopping service.